# Clip part of the page of PDF while drawing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am over-riding the drawLayer method to draw a particular page of the pdf. How can I clip a     part of the page and show the same.

```
 - (void)drawLayer:(CATiledLayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
    {   
     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // White

            CGContextFillRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context)); // Fill


            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height); CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

            CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(_PDFPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, true));


            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clip a part of the page if you set a clipping region on the context before drawing the PDF page.